# JFreecharts Demo Code does not build?

Tags: jfreechart

I purchased the Docs/support from `ObjectRefinery` for JFreeCharts. When running ant  the following occurs:

```
$ cd ant && ant
BUILD FAILED
/shared/jfreechart-1.0.19-demo/ant/build.xml:66: Warning: Could not find file
   /shared/jfreechart-1.0.19-demo/source/demo/orsoncharts/iStock_000003105870Small.jpg to copy.
```

Actually that file does not exist anywhere in the project -or *any* jpg for that matter:

```
freechart-1.0.19-demo $find . -name \*.jpg
 <no results>
```

So how to build this demo code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two files missing from the ZIP file which prevent the demo jar files from being rebuilt using the included Ant script.  This has been corrected and a new ZIP file uploaded to our server.  Additionally, your purchase has been refunded.

Comment: OK i'm downloading now to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

> Orsoncharts

is pervasive and broken within the build.xml `and within the source code` . The way to handle this is to:

- remove the couple dozen or so references to orsoncharts from that build file
- remove orson java sources
- remove references and usages of orson from demo/SuperDemo.java

and then do

```
ant -f ant/build.xml all
```

Guess what?   That is not enough. Now we get a supposedly unlicensed distro.

[image]

So we *still* can not work with the source code.  This whole ant-based mashup is a broken hack.

At this point the answer would be "Will the distributors put together a real buildable source distro (without Orson Charts) or not."

Comment: The build script will create two jar files, one that includes the source files (jfreechart-1.0.19-demo-src.jar) and one that doesn't (jfreechart-1.0.19-demo.jar).  You should run the former.