# JFreeCharts demo does not allows copy to clipboard from the Source panes?

Tags: jfreechart

In the screenshot below we see the (useful!) source code for an XYPlot chart. The problem is - well if I were to actually want to *use* the code .. how to do it? Notice that the **Edit menu item is disabled**.  So presumably there may have been cut and paste there .. but ..

So is there a workaround for this (well .. besides whipping out iTerm, cutting to the directory of the source and launching vim manually ..)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an oversight in the demo application.  The 'Edit' menu is used to copy and paste chart images when charts are being viewed.  The menu is disabled for the other tabs.

It does, of course, make sense that the user should be able to copy and paste the demo source code from the 'Source Code' tab rather than be required to find the relevant source file in the download.  I will update the code to enable this.

Comment: OK looking forward to it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to fix this in source code. However the whole ant/build.xml and even the codebase are  broken in multiple ways..  See here: [JFreecharts Demo Code does not build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31818166/jfreecharts-demo-code-does-not-build) .  I have contacted Object Refinery about a series of issues in their demo build script and setup.

Comment: The build issue has been fixed and a new ZIP file uploaded to our server.  Additionally, your purchase has been refunded.

Comment: The refund is less important than getting this working - but you are addressing both so thanks.